# Slurm Power Saving Plugin

Tags: slurm

I wrote a power saving plugin for Slurm so that I can use Slurm with a cloud provider.

I allocate nodes that can run multiple jobs at once. Let's say I can run 10 jobs/node.

Currently, if I request a job, it powers up a node (creates a cloud VM). If I immediately request a second job, Slurm powers up a second node.

I'd like Slurm to only power up a second node if the currently powering up first node can't also handle the new job. Otherwise, assign the new job to the currently powering up node as well.

Is this possible through configuration?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You just have to use `SelectType=select/cons_res` and specify the number of cores the node has in its configuration - because of the nature of cloud nodes, slurmctl will start without the possibility to check the number of cores on the node. In the case of per core resources tracking slurmctl allocates cores bitmaps on start, so the number of cores has to be specified in `slurm.conf`. It's very well described on [elastic computing for slurm page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/elastic_computing.html)

Comment: I'm already doing this. Once a node has been powered up, the SelectType properly assigns multiple jobs per node. However during power up it's powering up new unnecessary nodes (given that one node can handle more jobs than I'm asking to run).